# redirect cloudflare port to my custom port in Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, iptables, configure

I use port 32147 on my server for tls packet, but because this port is not supported in the domain that is connected to the Cloudflare proxy, so i use one of the ports supported by Cloudflare (for example, 2082) and i want in my server (with iptables rule) redirect to port 32147

probably I should also return the OUTPUT of port 32147 to port 2082 for outside of serve

please help me for this problem

i write this rule but not working

```
iptables -t nat -A preRouting -p tcp --dport 2082 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 32147
```

I use Ubuntu server 20.0.4